# Can you use/store your air compressor (horizontal cylinder type) in vertical position?

Tags: air-compressor

I have this Air Compressor. Can I remove the handle and store it and use it in vertical position (compressor facing me for easy access)

[image]

Comment: Is it an oil-less compressor? Shouldn't be a problem if that's the case, but if there's oil required, no.

Comment: Use? No.  Long-term-store?  Yes.  If you want a vertical compressor, *Craigslist For Sale/Trade: Horizontal compressor.  WTB: Vertical compressor.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a oil less compressor in just about any position will be fine but make sure to blow the water out of the tank prior to storing it.

Comment: Would you leave the plug out?+

Comment: what plug are you referring to?

Comment: I would not leave it plugged in running off axis could damage the pump but not storage, most compressors have a valve I open and dump the water but usually save the pressure in the tank.

Comment: The drain on the bottom that can be opened to let water out.

Comment: Yes the drain on the bottom.

Comment: Compressed air is much dryer (mass:mass ratio) than regular air, which is why condensate happens in the first place. Cracking the drain valve and allowing all possible liquid water to dribble out naturally with the departing air, should leave very little water in the tank. The remaining in-tank air, once decompressed to normal 1 ATM pressure, is very dry, and should gulp up what little water remains, still having a low relative humidity inside.